# How can I fill an array with a recordset of an unkown size?

Tags: vba

This is what I have right now.  I feel like this can't be the most efficient way, but I'm not sure how to do it without using the function to check if the array is empty for the first element.

```
marginrec.Open querystr, margincon

Do Until marginrec.EOF

    If Not IsNull(marginrec.Fields("term")) Then
        If Isarrempty(termarray) Then
            ReDim termarray(0)
            termarray(0) = marginrec.Fields("term")
        Else
            Ut = UBound(termarray)

            ReDim Preserve termarray(Ut + 1)

            termarray(Ut + 1) = marginrec.Fields("term")
        End If
    End If

    marginrec.movenext
Loop
```

-

```
Function Isarrempty(ByVal moagg As Variant) As Boolean

Dim b As Integer

On Error Resume Next

b = LBound(moagg)

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Isarrempty = True
Else
    Isarrempty = False
End If

On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Edit: I suppose I could count the records of the recordset too and then use one redim statement for that

Answer (score 3):

If the RecordSet will return a Count, use it with a ReDim, as your last edit states.

Sometimes Count always return zero, I think it depends on the type of cursor created with the RecordSet.

A work around is to create a second SQL statement, with the same Where clause,  that returns a count.

(`select count(*) ...`)

Run it first to set the ReDim...

Comment: The count will sometimes work if you do .MoveLast to get to the end of the recordset and then use .MoveFirst to get back to the beginning.

Comment: The unreliability of the `recordcount` property is what had me hesitant to use that.  I remember reading that you have to `MoveLast` and `MoveFirst` in order to get an accurate result.  However, it seems to be working without that requirement when I use the adOpenStatic cursortype.  Is there any reason to be worried about this going forward though?

Comment: if you're explicitly setting the cursor type and it works, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This question belongs in Code Review as it's working.  However, one way to do it is thus:

```
If Not marginRec.EOF Then
        ReDim termarray(0)
        termarray(0) = marginrec.Fields("term")
        marginRec.MoveNext
End If
Do Until marginRec.EOF
    Ut = UBound(termarray)
    ReDim Preserve termarray(Ut+1)
    termarray(Ut + 1) = marginrec.Fields("term")
    marginRec.MoveNext
Loop
```

Although as you mentioned in your edit, the BEST way would be to dimension it once as redimensioning the array every time takes a lot of time for no real purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to populate an array with values of a recordset field:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RecordsetToArray()

    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim objConnection As Object
    Dim objRecordSet As Object
    Dim arrField
    Dim lngUBound As Long
    Dim arrData() As String
    Dim i As Long

    ' connect to this workbook
    strConnection = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "User ID=Admin;" & _
        "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';" & _
        "Mode=Read;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;"";"
    ' select all data from sheet1
    strQuery = _
        "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$];"
    ' connect and query
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConnection.Open strConnection
    Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute(strQuery)
    ' convert selected field of the recordset to 2-dimensional array
    arrField = objRecordSet.GetRows(, , "ContactName")
    objConnection.Close
    ' get max index of the second dimension
    lngUBound = UBound(arrField, 2)
    ' set number of elements of target 1-dimensional array
    ReDim arrData(lngUBound)
    ' copy the values from 2d array to target array
    For i = 0 To lngUBound
        arrData(i) = arrField(0, i)
    Next

End Sub
```

`Sheet1` content, which is the sourse for that test query, is as follows:

[image: Source1.xlsx]

And the resulting `arrData` array contains the values from `'ContactName'` field:

[image: arrData content]

It works for me on Excel 2010 64 bit. As you can see, it's necessary to make `ReDim` only once, and number of elements can be computed by max index of 2-dimensional array, retrieved with [`GetRows` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms675120(v=vs.85).aspx).